# Image to fit a div automatically

Tags: html, css

I'm just looking for some advice on my approach to cloning a website. To improve my CSS skills, I've found a website that I'm basically trying to copy in order to get used to CSS syntax ect.

For the divs inside the wrapper, I'm given widths of 100% for them all, and a total height of wrapper 100vh. Between all the divs I've tried to 'approximate' what the height for each div would be - meaning I'm doing it manually. It looked well and good until I added an image (taken from the website) and inserted it into the div image. This resulted in only a portion of the image showing within the div, clearly my height approximation wasn't right. Meaning I had to give it more height, and the others divs less height to make it work. Clearly this isn't a great approach and was hoping for someone to suggest a better way.

```
 <div id = "wrapper">

    <div id = "header">

    </div>

    <div id = "navigation">
    </div>

    <div id = "image">
    </div>

    <div id = "repairs">
    </div>

    <div id = "whitespace">
    </div>

    <div id = "footer">
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper{
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    background-color: black;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

}

#header{
    width:100%;
    height:4vh;
    background-color: #ededed;
}

#navigation{
    width:100%;
    height:16vh;
    background-color:white;
}

#image {
    width:100%;
    height:30vh;
    background-image:url("image.png");

}

#repairs {
    width:100%;
    height:20vh;
    background-color:green;
}

#whitespace{
    width:100%;
    height:20vh;
    background-color:purple;

}

#footer{
    width:100%;
    height:10vh;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
height: auto;
```

Simply add this css

Answer (score 0):

You can add `background-size:contain` to the list of `#image` properties to make the background image fit completely inside the container, or use `background-size:cover` to make it completely cover the container.

If you use `contain`, you may also want to use something like `background-position: center center` to position it in the middle of the div.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

Comment: background-size contain - repeats the image twice within the container. When applying background-repeat: no-repeat; , the image then displays once full and the other half of the container is black due to body{background-color:black;)

Comment: Use `background-position` to place the image where you want it within the container, and change the background color with `background-color`.